# How to build this table by using colspan and rowspans?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-tables

Im new to html. Can someone help me how to do this kind of table? Im really having a hard time for this one since it is so complex. I tried several things but it makes it worse. Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQpfS.png)

Here is what I tried and the result is this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSBZ1.png)

I cant post the code since it restricts me to post too much code

Comment: can you provide what you have tried yourself?

Comment: okay. but the code is so long. is it okay to post it here? and also the result?

Comment: Make a snippet, and try to add only the minimal example

Comment: Okay will try it @Elikill58

Comment: here is the fiddle sir https://jsfiddle.net/e4u3oh5b/1/. I cannot paste the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.table{
        width: 50%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;   
    }
    .table td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 2px;
            
    }
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td colspan="2">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">text</td>
    <td rowspan="5">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td colspan="4">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td colspan="2">text</td>
    <td colspan="3">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td colspan="2">text</td>
    <td colspan="3">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td colspan="5">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td colspan="2">text</td>
    <td colspan="3">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Woah. this is extreme. Why are you so good with this?

Comment: how can i achive the space of the first cell?

Comment: I have deleted the text in the first cell and it looks okay. What's the problem?

Comment: its alright. i got it now. thanks bro

Comment: It seems you deal with lots of tables. Try an online generator where you could visually merge cells. I've found this: https://www.latex-tables.com/ (I haven't used it, just an idea of what you could look for).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td colspan="2" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td rowspan = "5" style="border:solid black; width:5px;"></td>
        <td rowspan="5" style="border:solid black; width:15px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td colspan="4" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td  style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td  style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td colspan="3" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td colspan="3" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td colspan="5" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td colspan="3" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
    <tr style="width:100%;height:30px;">
        <td colspan="7" style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
        <td style="border:solid black; width:20px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```